# Check if a string starts with any of the strings in an array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

In javascript, how can I check if a string starts with any of the strings in an array.

For example,

I have an array of strings,

```
const substrs = ['the', 'an', 'I'];
```

I have a string

```
const str = 'the car';
```

How can I check if str starts with any of the strings in substrs?

Comment: You could research how you can do that for _one_ string value, and then wrap a loop around it …

Comment: What about `the` and like `there was a car`? should that match or not?

Comment: use `['the', 'an', 'I'].toLocaleString()` to get `the,an,I` and you have two strings and can manipulate them

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use a combination of [`Array.prototype.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and [`String.prototype.startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith), both of which are ES6 features:

```js
const substrs = ['the', 'an', 'I'];
function checkIfStringStartsWith(str, substrs) {
  return substrs.some(substr => str.startsWith(substr));
}

console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('the car', substrs)); // true
console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('a car', substrs)); // false
console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('i am a car', substrs));  // false
console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('I am a car', substrs));  // true
```

If you want the comparsion to be done in a case-insensitive manner, then you will need to convert the string to lowercase as well:

```js
const substrs = ['the', 'an', 'I'];
function checkIfStringStartsWith(str, substrs) {
  return substrs.some(substr => str.toLowerCase().startsWith(substr.toLowerCase()));
}

console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('the car', substrs)); // true
console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('a car', substrs)); // false
console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('i am a car', substrs));  // true (case-insensitive)
console.log(checkIfStringStartsWith('I am a car', substrs));  // true
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to build a regex alternation of the keywords in the `substrs` array.  Then, use `test()` on the input to check for a match:

```js
const substrs = ['the', 'an', 'I'];
const str = 'the car';
regexp = new RegExp('^(?:' + substrs.join('|') + ')\\b');
console.log(regexp);
if (regexp.test(str)) {
    console.log("MATCH");
}
```

Here I have also printed out the regular expression being used so that it is clear.

Comment: Careful with this approach. This works only as long as the strings in the array don't contain any characters that have special meaning in a regular expression; most likely `.`, `+` and `*`. Then you need to start thinking about escaping things and it becomes an even more overengineered solution.

Comment: @Thomas Escaping a regex in JS is fairly easy, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446170/escape-string-for-use-in-javascript-regex), in fact Node has a built in function for this.  _You_ are the one overengineering the question, as we have no strong reason to believe that the keywords would be anything but word characters only.

Comment: You just don't need regex for this.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const substrs = ['the', 'an', 'I'];
const str = 'the car';

let result = substrs.filter(s => str.startsWith(s));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: @jfriend00 No, Please reread mycode properly. `str.startsWith(s)` here what is str and what is s?

Comment: OP is is looking for sentences that start with words  `I` , `the` , `an`. In your case `and`,`Interest`,`them` are also considered.

Comment: Man, that is one confusing way to write things.

Comment: @AkshayGaonkar Read the question properly first

Comment: Well, you can be surprised at how dumb you think I am OR you can realize that maybe writing the code that uses methods in an unusual way might confuse people. It also seems wasteful to create a whole output array when all the OP wants is a boolean.  I didn't downvote you - I just was confused by this code the first time I saw it and I shared that in a comment and I think that's a relevant comment to answers here. Also, telling people to reread something RATHER than just explaining in words how your answer works isn't the best way to clarify your answer or clear up confusion or earn votes.

Comment: Posting code without explanation is rarely helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
const check = (arr, str) => {
    const firstWord = str.substr(0, str.indexOf(" "));
    return arr.includes(firstWord);
}

const substrs = ['thee', 'an', 'I', 'The', 'the'];
const str = 'the car';

console.log(check(substrs, str)); //true
```